# Retrieve first and last name of the current Windows user?

Tags: java

I know you can retrieve the *username* with something like `System.getProperty("user.name")` but I am looking for a way to retrieve the *first and last name* of the current user.

Is there a native Java library that does this? Or do you have to plug into the Windows API? Or maybe you have to pull it from Active Directory? This seems relatively easy [with .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471635/get-first-name-last-name-of-logedin-windows-user) but I can't find a way to do it in Java.

Comment: I don't have the answer but you might look at [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) and see if that would help.

Comment: How do you do it with .NET?  If it's a system call, it can be done in Java with JNA.

Comment: Added a link to how to do it in .NET. Considering just tapping into ActiveDirectory, but I thought for sure there it would be simpler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Brian Roach suggested in the comments, it's pretty straight-forward to do this with JNA, since it has [a built-in wrapper for Secur32](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Secur32.java) which wraps the [GetUsernameEx() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (which is ultimately the system call wrapped by the .NET library you linked to above).

Use would be something like this:

```
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Secur32;

// ...    

char[] name = new char[100];  // or whatever is appropriate
Secur32.INSTANCE.GetUserNameEx(
     Secur32.EXTENDED_NAME_FORMAT.NameDisplay,
     name,
     new IntByReference(name.length)
);

String fullName = new String(name).trim();
```

Note that this will give you the full name in the same format as you'd get typing `net user %USERNAME% /domain` at the command prompt.

Comment: I was hot on the trail of this and you beat me to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Or just,

```
String fullName = Secur32Util.getUserNameEx(Secur32.EXTENDED_NAME_FORMAT.NameDisplay);
```

But it is the same, as the upper answer