# Get the details of currently logged in user

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I am making an application where the authentication to that is bind to Azure Active Directory.

I need to get the first name and last name of logged in user.
Currently I am able to get username by using

```
public string name
{
    get
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    }
}
```

It returns me "Subham.kumar@nathcorp.com", but I don't need the whole username.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471635/how-do-i-get-the-first-name-and-last-name-of-the-logged-in-windows-user

Comment: Why is your question tagged with javascript and jQuery? They seem unrelated to the issue

Comment: I am free to use javascript and Jquery instead of c#.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Claims

```
        foreach (Claim cl in ((ClaimsIdentity)(User.Identity)).Claims)
        {
            switch (cl.Type)
            {
                case ClaimTypes.Email:
                    currentUser.Mail = cl.Value;
                    break;
                case ClaimTypes.Name:
                case ClaimTypes.Surname:
                    currentUser.Name = cl.Value;
                    break;
                case ClaimTypes.GivenName:
                    currentUser.FirstName = cl.Value;
                    break;
             }
         }
```