# Get Windows UserPrincipal DisplayName and Change Order

Tags: c#

I'm having an issue with the way a `DisplayName` is shown when getting the name of a computer user. Currently I use

```
public static string fullName = UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName;
```

which returns "LastName, FirstName (Department)".

I need to have them displayed in the format of "FirstName LastName".

Is there a recommended way to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at the `Name` property?

Comment: You can split the value by comma and have first item as last name and determine the first name by getting SubString from 0 to the first index of `(` in the second item.

Comment: this is for a reason. mainly for lookup when sorted alphabetically. in your program, you are free to query for `sn` and `givenName` and compose them as you see fit, via LDAP. .NET has wrappers around this starting in version 3.0, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3471954/1132334) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699904/1132334)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting in Microsoft.NET 3.0, the `UserPrincipal` class exposes the parts of the name (as [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.givenname(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

/* ... */

var principal = UserPrincipal.Current;
var firstname = principal.GivenName;
var middlename = principal.MiddleName;
var lastname = principal.Surname;

var customcomposite = $"{firstname} {lastname}".TrimStart();
```