# Using Wildcard in Windows Firewall

Tags: windows, scripting, wildcard, windows-firewall

We are using Turbo.net for Publishing applications. One of this application (designed by our own Company) uses a Broadcast to find devices in the Network and then get a reply by a dynamic UDP Port (30000 - 50000). Opening all These ports on the Windows Firewall is not an Option.

I have therefore tried to specify the exe file in the Windows Firewall. That works but the Problem is, I Need to do this for 200 users. So I want to do this by GPO. Unfortunately the path to the exe is something like this:

%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Spoon\Servers\apps.elpro.com\Users\Firstname.Lastname.Domain\Sandboxes\ECOLOGPROModuleConfigurator__1-4-8-420__en-us__Default__AnyCpu\local\stubexe\0x4D80DB43F65B57C8\ PROModuleConfigurator.exe

The problem is "\Firstname.Lastname.Domain\". I was not able to find a way to use a wildcard for this in the Windows Firewall.

It seems that Windows-Firewall does not allow Wildcards.

Is there an easy fix for this or do I Need to script something and if how?

Thank you!

Comment: did you manage to find any solution for this?

Comment: as of 23-05-25 ,windows don't support wildcard, in its document : Best practices for configuring Windows Defender Firewall | Microsoft Learn
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/operating-system-security/network-security/windows-firewall/best-practices-configuring    , it say : The use of wildcard patterns, such as C:*\teams.exe is not supported in application rules. We currently only support rules created using the full path to the application(s).

Answer (score -1):

The fact that it can handle `%userprofile%` tells you that it's okay with Windows variables, so the thing to do would be to set up more such variables, to pass this path as `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Spoon\Servers\apps.elpro.com\Users\%Firstname%.%Lastname%.Domain\`...

Sorry there's not a copy-paste solution for you.  It would take some scripting on your end to pull this name data out of Active Directory (or some Linux/Unix LDAP server – whatever your organization is using) and fill these variables on a per-user basis.  On the up-side, the variables could have other uses once you get them set up, like naming backup directories on a NAS in `%Lastname%, %Firstname%` format, and so on.

Exactly how to do this will vary by coding language, by OS version, and by directory service type. The information about this is scattered far and wide, so you'll have to search around a bit.  E.g., for how to get an AD user's real names with C# under dotNet 3.0+, see [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471635/how-do-i-get-the-first-name-and-last-name-of-the-logged-in-windows-user).  And there are [lots of SO threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=first+name+get-aduser) with info on using `Get-ADUser` in Powershell to find and filter by user's IDs and names. [This thread on SpiceWorks](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1451053-powershell-pull-first-last-name-samaccountname-whencreated-groups) might also be of interest.

**You'll almost certainly need** [Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/system-management-components/remote-server-administration-tools) (see that page for installation details, which are totally different depending on OS version, even within Windows 10!). Tools that deal with ActiveDirectory need the AD stuff in RSAT to do their work, including both Powershell and C#.Net.  RSAT requires Windows Pro or Enterprise (on the machine you're going to use to do the AD work; user workstations can be any version). But AD itself requires Windows Server.

This is only going to be doable with an Active Directory or other LDAP server, in which this user firstname/lastname information, as such, is even stored.  Local accounts do not have this information at all except when they inherit it in munged "full name" form, e.g. from Microsoft.com account credentials.  In Powershell, you can run 'Get-LocalUser | Select *', or follow the more "deep dive" local-ADSI method [demonstrated here](https://www.lepide.com/how-to/list-all-user-accounts-on-a-windows-system-using-powershell.html), and you'll find no first and last name data. It's just not part of an account, absent some systemic means (AD, or Microsoft online account connection, or Microsoft Family Group management, etc.) of injecting it. There are [multiple ways of manually adding "full name"](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-add-your-full-name-local-account-windows-10), but even doing this across a bunch of users probably would not help you, since human names are not easily software-parseable into first name and last name (Many people have two last names, and many have two or more given names; so what is "Pat Morgan Otero"? And of course given-name versus family-name order varies culturally.) There appears to be no way to add separate first and last name fields to local accounts; tools like `Set-LocalUser` cannot do it.

[aside]There's no connection between Windows user data and Windows Subsystem for Linux user data (even the usernames can be different), so that's no help.  *If* you have a network-wide unified user ID system via LDAP or whatever, *and* it has an end result of everyone's user IDs and their real names being in account information under any Linux/Unix system on your network (print server, NAS, anything you can get privileged shell access to), then you might have an easier go of it, given the text-processing tools available to `bash` in Linux/Unix (including macOS), like `grep` and `sed` and `awk`. All you'd need is a command-line tool for accessing LDAP (or whatever) to run directory queries, then parse the results for name information. Or that name info might even already exist in that Linux box's `passwd` file.  This was how I did something similar for one client, but it was a Linux-heavy shop. If you have any (or most) users isolated from Linux in a Windows-only sphere of users, then this approach would not work.[/aside]

It looks like accessing AD data (or LDAP, whatever) in Windows with Windows-based scripting/programming is the only certain way to do what you want to do. Even then, it will only work if the data is present and correct.  You'd need group policy that doesn't permit people to change their names (e.g. by removing their surname) once their account is configured, and human procedural rules that admins must enter this data when setting up accounts, and that it be correct and complete (not missing surname, and not be placeholder or role data that might be substituted out later or might even occur on multiple machines).

PS: Ultimately, I think you should write to the creators of that software and ask them to stop using first and last names in paths, as it breaks the administrability of their product.